# Nuances of different Korean words for "discipline"

Tags: translation

There are quite a few Korean noun options for the word "discipline" (징계, 훈련, 학과, 기율, 억제), and I am trying to figure out which word(s) are most appropriate for conveying the virtue of self-discipline (and **not** "discipline" in the sense of "punishment" or "academic field"). For example, if I wished to tell someone who eats too much junk food or watches TV instead of studying that they need to have more "discipline", what word(s) would be most appropriate?

Comment: See 절제하다, 조절하다. I'd say "TV 보고 군것질하는 것 절제도 할 줄 알아야 한다." or "시간 조절해 가며 TV 봐라."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had to say 'you lack self-discipline' or 'you need to be more disciplined about it,' that might be:

> 너는 자제력이 부족해. (You have an insufficient degree of the power of self-control.)

or

> 너는 자제력을 좀 길러야 해. (You need to increase/nurture the power of self-control a bit.)

Or 'this is a matter of discipline' (meaning 'self-discipline') might be:

> 이건 자제력의 문제야.  (This is a matter of the power of self-control).

---

However, you lose much background by translating in this case.  Discipline is what a 'disciple' undergoes.  When the disciple misbehaves there may be a 'disciplinary' committee.  After years of that, the student may now have 'self-discipline' and can behave in a 'disciplined' manner, and so on.  Thus, to an English speaker 'discipline' may figure as an obvious ingredient of success along with such things as 'motivation' and 'opportunity.'

A concept more natural to a Korean speaker may be effort, or 노력.  If someone gives up on a program of exercise or study, the comment may be:

> 너는 노력이 부족해.  (You lack effort--or are not trying hard enough.)

If the (given up) thing had to be put up with rather than pursued, the comment may go to patience.

> 너는 참을성이 부족해.  (You lack patience.)

I realize these don't work very well for binge eating or TV (which does not obviously require effort or patience). These, I believe, a Korean speaker is likely to connect to some pursuit, e.g. losing weight or studying.  Then the binge behavior can be re-cast as lack of effort or patience in that pursuit.

If the Korean speaker does say '자제력,' it may sound more fresh or original than a reference to 'discipline' in English.

Answer (score 0):

I think 절제 is the word you are looking for. You can say "사람이 절제 할 줄도 알아야지."